# Ways to check the result of multiplying matrices?

Tags: c++, math, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a simple C++ programm that multiplies: matrix * matrix:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, m, r, i, j, k, si;

    cout << "Dimension 1: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Dimension 2: ";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "Dimension 3: ";
    cin >> r;


    int * A = new int[n * m];
    int * B = new int[m * r];
    int * C = new int[n * r];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) cin >> A[i * m + j];

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < r; j++) cin >> B[i * r + j];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < r; j++)
        {
            si = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < m; k++)
                si += A[i * m + k] * B[k * r + j];
            C[i * r + j] = si;
        }

    cout << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < r; j++) cout << C[i * r + j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

What are the ways to check the results if matrices are really big (ex. 1000x1000)? (i mean using programming language, not mathematically)

Comment: Why don't you check correctness of your code on small matrices, say, 3x3 or 4x4? If small matrices work ok (and cover all edge cases), you only need to check for overflow and performance on large cases.

Comment: Lots of Google results for "matrix test data"

Comment: How do you know your check routine is correct?

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 My main goal is NOT to find out if my results are correct, but find an algorithm/way to calculate the results the other way, in other words: implement a solution that checks the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean checking for correct implementation.

There are a couple of ways to do that:

**1.** Proof of correctness through inductive reasoning (if it works for n = 1 and n = 2 etc., it also works with n = 1000)

**2.** Implement a different alogrithm, that achieves the same result and compare both results for varying input sizes.

If you truly want to make sure your algorithm works for a defined set of input variables, you can also write a [formal proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification) (by that point you are pretty much sure it is correct.)

Comment: Good points. Actually i am trying to implement a solution that checks the first approach. Can you propose any algorithm that you mentioned in point 2.?

Comment: You can attempt to implement this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm. It is also significantly faster than your method, which is the standard approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate test data using another well established software. Try MATLAB [matrix generators](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gallery.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) .